# How to determine UIView orientation/heading?

Tags: iphone, uiview, rotation, cllocationmanager

In my app I'm rotating a UIView according to a Iphone heading(heading from CLLocationManager).
I'm rotating this UIView with this function:

```
[UIView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(theHeading))]
```

Somewhere there is a problem and my view rotates wrong. 
I'm looking for way to check in what heading my view right now and correct it, or another better way to rotate it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why can't you just log what the last call to setTransform set as the angle? Then you can see what was set when it goes wrong.

Comment: i do it, but there some problem that i can't detect: after one of the rotation the angle that i log os correct but the view still changes to another angle.